# How to control visibility of primitives from Cesium3DTileset

Tags: javascript, visibility, cesiumjs

How to correctly control the visibility of primitives from `Cesium3DTileset`?

First I create a checkbox element in `HTML`, and a checkbox `addEventListener` to control the visibility of DataSource from my local `geojson` file. And it goes well.

And then I did the same thing to control whether the `3DTile` from my Cesium ion account needs to be shown. At the fist check and uncheck, everything goes well. But the second time when I check the box, nothing shows up in the scene. And the second time of uncheck do nothing and no error as well.

```
//this is my checkbox elements
    <input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox1" > geojson1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox2" > geojson2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox_1" > ion_1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showCheckbox_2" > ion_2<br>


//this is my first try to control the visibility of geojson, and it goes well
    var obj1 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
    obj.load('../DataSource/GeoJson/airport_cesium2.geojson')
    var obj2 = new Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource();
    obj2.load('../DataSource/GeoJson/LiangMau.geojson')

    function handleCheckbox(id,datasource){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            // Checkbox state changed.
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                // Show if not shown.
                if (!viewer.dataSources.contains(datasource)) {
                    viewer.dataSources.add(datasource);
                }
            } else {
                // Hide if currently shown.
                if (viewer.dataSources.contains(datasource)) {
                    viewer.dataSources.remove(datasource);
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
    handleCheckbox('showCheckbox1',obj1)
    handleCheckbox('showCheckbox2',obj2)


//then I try to control the visibility of 3DTile
    var obj_1 = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
        url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(35386)
    })
    var obj_2 = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
        url: Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(35381)
    })

    function handleCheckbox_(id,datasource){
        var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            // Checkbox state changed.
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                // Show if not shown.
                if (!scene.primitives.contains(datasource)) {
                    scene.primitives.add(datasource);
                }
            } else {
                // Hide if currently shown.
                if (scene.primitives.contains(datasource)) {
                    scene.primitives.remove(datasource);
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
    handleCheckbox_('showCheckbox_1',obj_1)
    handleCheckbox_('showCheckbox_2',obj_2)
```

I can control the visibility of `3DTile` at the first check and uncheck, but nothing happens at the second time. It really confuse me because there is no error showing, and I don't know what do next.

Comment: I don't think adding and removing multiple times is the right thing to do.  Is there a `.show` flag you can toggle?  I know dataSource has a `show` flag, I don't recall if primitive does.

Comment: You are right, I found out what was wrong.  .show is the answer I need, it works well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the answer for this turned out to be to set the `dataSource.show` flag to toggle the visibility.  Adding and removing the same dataSource multiple times was the problem, as typically when a dataSource is removed it is being destroyed.  So, toggling visibility with the `show` flag is preferred.